# What is a flag? What is the pygame.SRCALPHA flag used for (I came across that in the example aacircle.py)?

Tags: pygame

I know almost nothing about pygame, and I'm trying to learn by messing with the examples. Also I'm reading the documentation and might try some tutorials.

I'm coming from a background of javascript with processing.js which I learned on khan academy's computer science section.

Anyways in the documentation for surface objects (page 4 of the pdf I downloaded) it says "For a plain software surface, 0 can be used for the flag." So as one of my first experiments I changed pygame.SRCALPHA in the example aacircle.py to a zero and tested it out. The screen went from bliting a red background with a black circle, to just solid black. Why?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you check out the [pygame documentation on surfaces](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

> The pixel format can be controlled by passing the bit depth or an
> existing Surface. The flags argument is a bitmask of additional
> features for the surface. You can pass any combination of these flags:
>
> HWSURFACE, creates the image in video memory
>
> SRCALPHA, the pixel format will include a per-pixel alpha